# How to download with wget a release jar from my private github repo?

Tags: git, repository, wget, github-api

my question is about wget and github.
I have a private repo in github and built a release, tag release-3, appHappy.jar.
Now the challenge is to download the the appHappy.jar from the private repo tag release-3 with wget.
I also made an private token(with all grants) and then I wrote this statement

```
$wget --header='Authorization: token HappyFakeToken' https://api.github.com/repos/speedyG/privateRepo/releases/releases-3/appHappy.jar
```

but I get a 404: Not Found...

what's wrong?

I read already, but I have no idea how solve the problem...
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

The URLs for assets aren't listed directly under the repository, and the release ID is an integer, not a string.  The easiest way to do this is to query the releases endpoint for your repository and then search the JSON for the appropriate `browser_download_url` endpoint.

For example, if I wanted to download the file `git-lfs-v2.9.0.tar.gz` from the latest Git LFS release (v2.9.0), I'd do this to find the URL:

```
wget -O- https://api.github.com/repos/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases | \
  jq -r '.[] | select (.name == "v2.9.0") | .assets | .[] | 
         select(.name == "git-lfs-v2.9.0.tar.gz") | .browser_download_url'
```

I'd then use that URL in a future `curl` or `wget` command to download it.  Note that this endpoint is paginated; if there are a large number of releases, you may need to walk through the pages.  At that point, it may be better to pick a language other than shell.